# ArgumentException in Rx. Where should be thrown?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I don't know when I should throw an ArgumentException while creating IObservable. Should I throw it before Create method or within?

This:

```
IObservable<object> CreateObservable(int i)
{
    if (i < 0)
        throw new ArgumentException();

    return Observable.Create(o => { ... });
}
```

Vs:

```
IObservable<object> CreateObservable(int i)
{
    return Observable.Create(o =>
    {
        if (i < 0)
            o.OnError(new ArgumentException());

        ...
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you [fail fast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast), and therefore your first option is in my opinion correct.
If you were to use the second option, the consumer would only get the exception when they subscribed to the sequence, which may be some time later. This would make for a far more difficult code base to maintain IMO.